# How many objects are shared between groups?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, algorithm

I'm working through planning a rails database and I'm struggling to develop an algorithm and structure for the database. An object  can belong to multiple buckets. Object 0x01 can be in A, B, C and 0x02 in B, D. If I query after just one object then:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 1
D = 1

A&B = 2
A&C = 1
```

Want to return:

```
Total count in bucket A, B, C, D ... (separately)
Total count shared between A&B, B&C, C&D, A&C, A&D, ...
Total count shared between A&B&C, A&B&D, B&C&D ... (every combination).
```

I do not want to save the specific values for each individual object.

Is this a way to save this data in a database without growing the database exponentially? I only want to save total counts.

Answer (score 0):

my friend , u need to use a quiet punch of counters and nested loops for that . 
for example if i wanna check counts for A&&B : 
for ( Object in A ) 
    for ( Object in  B )
        if theres a match , increment ur counter . 
hopefully this may help you